# Running very lightweight tasks periodically with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Consider a requirement where we need to run very simple and lightweight tasks , say running curl command every 10 minutes.

If this was to run in a kubernetes cluster , is it efficient to create a container every 10 minutes ? Just to execute a task that may take a few seconds or even millisecond ? Is it an overkill from time and cost angle ?

Please note unfortunately lambda functions or cloud functions is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to run Jobs on a time-based schedule. These automated jobs run like Cron tasks on a Linux or UNIX system. Cron jobs are useful for creating periodic and recurring tasks.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

Comment: Thanks .. but even with Cros jobs kubernetes would still launch a new container at every iteration.

Comment: yes that's right...but the container will be terminated automatically and you can configure the requests and limits of the container to be very low to reduce resource consumption

Comment: Agree with @ArghyaSadhu, you can see that for example [Knative](https://knative.dev/) was designed to treat your Kubernetes clusters as a serverless platform like AWS Lambda, it assumes that the containers will be fast on startup so they can be created and destroyed on every call. Same goes for your use case, if you deploy a tiny, fast and low-resource-consuming container, CronJob should do the job for you.

Comment: Thank @AdamBarreiro ... I was checking within our team and someone quoted Knative ..